# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this problem while installing rails on Windows 10. 
I have tried to many things but none of them worked. Please help!!!
This is what I have done. It looks like I have two errors.
  **ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**
  **You have to install development tools first.**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\Perdorues>ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\Perdorues>gem -v
2.6.10

C:\Users\Perdorues>gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri
Fetching: i18n-0.8.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.8.1
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.5
Fetching: activesupport-5.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.1.0
Fetching: nokogiri-1.7.0.1-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
Nokogiri is built with the packaged libraries: libxml2-2.9.4, libxslt-1.1.29, zlib-1.2.8, libiconv-1.14.
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.7.0.1-x64-mingw32
Fetching: loofah-2.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed loofah-2.0.3
Fetching: rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3
Fetching: rails-dom-testing-2.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-dom-testing-2.0.2
Fetching: builder-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.3
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Fetching: actionview-5.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-5.0.2
Fetching: actionpack-5.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-5.0.2
Fetching: activemodel-5.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-5.0.2
Fetching: arel-7.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arel-7.1.4
Fetching: activerecord-5.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-5.0.2
Fetching: globalid-0.3.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed globalid-0.3.7
Fetching: activejob-5.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activejob-5.0.2
Fetching: mime-types-data-3.2016.0521.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-data-3.2016.0521
Fetching: mime-types-3.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-3.1
Fetching: mail-2.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mail-2.6.4
Fetching: actionmailer-5.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionmailer-5.0.2
Fetching: nio4r-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.0.0/ext/nio4r
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170312-10676-aq6a8o.rb extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to    generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.0.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.0.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could list the things you've tried. On windows I'd recommend using something like http://railsinstaller.org/en or even a virtual environment like a vagrant box.

Comment: Is there a solid reason why you are not preferring to use the de facto rails installer for Windows?

Comment: Have you installed the development kit from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/?  FWIW: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ also recommends using 2.2.X installers and states that the "64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it.'

Comment: I tried also to install it from [link](http://railsinstaller.org/en), it shows me this:
    C:\Sites>gem install bundler  
    Fetching: bundler-1.14.6.gem (100%)  
    Successfully installed bundler-1.14.6  
    Parsing documentation for bundler-1.14.6  
    Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.14.6  
    Done installing documentation for bundler after 28 seconds
   1 gem installed

   C:\Sites>rails -v
   The system cannot find the path specified.
@bork

Answer (score -1):

When using ruby on Windows with I presume ruby installer you should also install [ruby development kit](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). I think this will solve your problem.